# class sanctum\\personal access token not found

Tags: laravel, postman, token

I have issue during register any user in the sanctum. I newly install sanctum to my Laravel and I got this issue after I give user and password and email in postman its giving me the below issue:

```bash
    "message": "Class \"App\\Models\\PersonalAccessToken\" not found",
    "exception": "Error",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\apiapp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Concerns\\HasRelationships.php",
    "line": 745,
```

Even though the user is created, it does not give a token.

Below is my `userController`:

```php
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $fields = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|string|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed'
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $fields['name'],
            'email' => $fields['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($fields['password'])
        ]);

        $token = $user->createToken('myapptoken')->plainTextToken;

        $response = [
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token
        ];
        return response($response); 
}
```

Here is my model user

[image]

Comment: Can you show the User model please

Comment: i added please help i am around one week in this issue

Comment: check the imge which i shared newly

Answer (score 1):

I think you tried to follow the official tutorial [Overriding Default Models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#overriding-default-models).
The tutorial shows how to place the class to the AppServiceProvider.php file:

```
use App\Models\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken; // this line will produce error
use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Sanctum::usePersonalAccessTokenModel(PersonalAccessToken::class);
}
```

to solve this problem, just create the class which has been mentioned before and place to the right namespace:

```
namespace App\Models\Sanctum; // place your file to Models/Sanctum/PersonalAccessToken.php
use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken as SanctumPersonalAccessToken;

class PersonalAccessToken extends SanctumPersonalAccessToken
{
    // ...
}
```

and if you wanna custom your User Model class as like your current problem:
[image]

you added the line: `use App\Models\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken;`, so you must create this missing class to the right place as like I explained above.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing to add the `HasApiTokens` trait to your user model.

```php
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
}
```

Comment: i already added but still the issue is there  what to do ?

Comment: Can you help me pro i really need urgent help please  even i can give you my anydesk to fix it together

Comment: I saw the user model you shared. I dont see:
`use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;`
imported anywhere.

Comment: its there is added  and still not working its in my model user

Comment: can i give you my anydesk to check togather ?

Comment: check the pic which is there  i updated you can see

Comment: In the pic you have  `use App\Models\PersonalAccessToken` you dont need that.  Remove that line and the model. If you need to modify the PersonallAccessToken you must follow the documentation: [link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#overriding-default-models)

Comment: i deleted its still the same i follow the same steps in document

Answer (score -1):

you should use
this

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;
```

instead of

```
`use App\Models\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken;`
   `use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;`
```

Comment: Maybe, but Sanctum does support a custom PersonalAccessToken model to be used like OP appears to be doing. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#overriding-default-models

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).